# How to show only the first by hover with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

if i make a hover over my menulinks currently all submenues which are on the first level will be shown
i dont know whats wrong, see my code:

```
    $('#menu li').hover(function () {
        //show its submenu
        $('ul', this).slideDown(100);

    }, function () {
        //hide its submenu
        $('ul', this).slideUp(100);
    });
```

so in my opinion it must work very well because a hover over a link should only display this first submenu. But also the submenu of this first link will show directly by a hover and i dont know how to fix it better than yet.

need some help please.

For a better understanging i hve created a [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/astonmartin/km9PT/).

Answer (score 7):

Your selector in your hover functions are finding all `ul` elements that are descendants of the `li` element. You want to show only direct children. Try this instead:

```
$('#menu li').hover(function() {
    //show its submenu
    $(this).children('ul').slideDown(100);

}, function() {
    //hide its submenu
    $(this).children('ul').slideUp(100);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The `<ul>` which is holding your submenus also contains the sub-submenus. So if you display the first list, it automatically also shows all elements contained in that list.

Answer (score 0):

you should separate the `ul` for different levels of submenu using different class for different levels of menus.

if you want to just change your code you might want to try this change:

```
//show its submenu
$('ul', this).eq(0).slideDown(100);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the list you want to show. Use `$(this)` as context to find the `<ul>` inside, and then filter the result with the `:first` pseudo-selector.

Try something like this for both `hoverIn` and `hoverOut` events:

```
$("#menu").on('hover', 'li', function(e){
    // $(this) refers to the <li> being hovered
    $(this).find('ul:first').slideToggle(100);
});
```

See the docs for [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) and [`slideToggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/) methods.